# Memory profiling within build process with MSBuild

Tags: testing, msbuild, profiling, .net

Among other things we are using automated UI-Tests within our build process with MSBuild. Due to some problems we are looking now for a memory profiler that can be integrated within the build process and collect information (interesting values, errors, warnings, ...) during runnning the UI-Test.

The api's of memory profiler I found (e.g. [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)) doesn't seem to have good support for msbuild!? Has somebody experiences or a solution with such a problem?

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

You can use VSPerfASPNETCmd tool w/ command-line support.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255376.aspx

You'll need to integrate it into post-build event or make it an msbuild task.